# Use tkinter virtual event from thread

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter

I would like to update a Tkinter Label from a Thread using a virtual event.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import threading
import time


def run_test_event():
    while True:
        root.event_generate("<<test_eventA>>")
        root.event_generate("<<test_eventB>>")
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    l = ttk.Label(root, text="Starting...")
    l.grid()
    l.bind('<Enter>', lambda e: l.configure(text='Moved mouse inside'))
    l.bind('<<test_eventA>>', lambda e: l.configure(text='test_eventA'))
    l.bind('<<test_eventB>>', print('test_eventB'))

    threading.Thread(target=run_test_event).start()
    root.mainloop()
```

Console print this at startup:

```
test_eventB
```

Console print this when GUI is closed:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1849, in event_generate
    self.tk.call(args)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
```

Label is never updated and does not display `test_eventA`

Setting the Thread as daemon does help. It avoid to generate above Exception but still the label is not updated.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are generating the virtual event on root window, not the label.  You should call `.event_generate()` on the label:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import threading
import time


def run_test_event(label):
    while True:
        label.event_generate("<<test_eventA>>")
        label.event_generate("<<test_eventB>>")
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    l = ttk.Label(root, text="Starting...")
    l.grid()
    l.bind('<Enter>', lambda e: l.configure(text='Moved mouse inside'))
    l.bind('<<test_eventA>>', lambda e: l.configure(text='test_eventA'))
    l.bind('<<test_eventB>>', lambda e: print('test_eventB')) # should use lambda here

    # pass label to target function
    threading.Thread(target=run_test_event, args=(l,), daemon=True).start()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think the call to `label.event_generate()` needs the argument `when='tail'` when it is invoked in a thread, in order to place the event in Tcl's event queue instead of processing it immediately. If you don't do that, I think the thread will run the callbacks instead of the main thread.